# Correcting for selection bias with standardisation/g-computation

Tags: causality, standardization, selection-bias

Two sets of methods for correcting for selection bias are g-computation (standardisation) and inverse probability of censoring weighting (IPCW). I'm having a difficult time understanding how to apply the former.

As a demonstration, I generate some data from the following DAG - Figure 8.4 from Hernan and Robins [Causal Inference](https://www.hsph.harvard.edu/miguel-hernan/causal-inference-book/):
[image: Figure 8.4 Causal Inference]

$A$ is a binary treatment, $Y$ is a continuous outcome, $C$ indicates censoring (e.g. loss to follow-up), and $U$ is an unmeasured variable. The true causal effect is zero (there are no paths from A into Y).

```
library(tidyverse)

sim_data <- function(n,seed){
  set.seed(seed)
  A <- rbinom(n, 1, 0.5)
  U <- rnorm(n)
  L <- rbinom(n, 1, plogis(-0.5 + A + U))
  C <- rbinom(n, 1, plogis(-1 + 3*L))
  Y <- U + rnorm(n)
  tibble(A,L,C,Y)
}

df <- sim_data(n=100000,seed=123)
```

Recovering the true treatment effect requires no backdoor paths between $Y$ and $A$ (which holds unconditional on $L$, a collider) and no backdoor paths between $Y$ and $C$ (which requires adjustment for $L$).

Recovering the true treatment effect seems pretty straightforward by IPCW:

```
# IPC weighting
C_model <- 
  glm(C==0 ~ L, data = df, family = binomial)

df$ipc_weights <- 
  1/predict(C_model, newdata = df, 
            type = "response")

Y_model <- 
  lm(Y ~ A, 
     data = filter(df, C == 0), 
     weights = 
       filter(df, C == 0)$ipc_weights)

coef(Y_model)["A"]
#0.0001701217
```

Another option is g-computation. The formula given in [this paper](https://academic.oup.com/ije/article/47/5/1714/5048424?login=false), as I've (mis)interpreted it and adapted to this example, is:
$$\sum_lE[Y|A=1,L=l,C=0]-E[Y|A=0,L=l,C=0]Pr[L=l]$$

When I apply this approach, however, I'm consistently getting the wrong answer. E.g.

```
# G-computation
df_c <- filter(df, C == 0)

treated_L0 <- 
  mean(df_c[df_c$A == 1 & df_c$L==0,]$Y)
treated_L1 <- 
  mean(df_c[df_c$A == 1 & df_c$L==1,]$Y)
untreated_L0 <- 
  mean(df_c[df_c$A == 0 & df_c$L==0,]$Y)
untreated_L1 <- 
  mean(df_c[df_c$A == 0 & df_c$L==1,]$Y)

Pr_L0 <- sum(df$L==0)/nrow(df)
Pr_L1 <- 1 - Pr_L0

out <- ((treated_L0 - untreated_L0)*Pr_L0) +
  ((treated_L1 - untreated_L1)*Pr_L1)

out
# -0.1629754
```

Where am I going wrong here? My instinct is that I should not be summing over $Pr[L=l]$ but instead over $Pr[L=l|A=a]$ (which does seem to give the right answer), but I don't really understand why, if that is the case. Any help much appreciated!

Comment: I don't think the causal effect is identified with g-computation here. Conditioning on $L$ doesn't remove the selection bias.

Comment: @Noah You may well be right. I had the intuitive impression that because IP weighting and standardisation are mathematically equivalent, there couldn't be a situation in one worked but not the other. But there seems to be no way around conditioning on L with g-computation.

Comment: Yep, Hernan and Robins actually address the exact case you're mentioning later on (see Ch. 8.5) -- in short, for IPCW, you're not really "directly" conditioning on L when you come up with your final estimate of the ATE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I appreciate both comments to the question, but standardization/g-computation is identified here. The issue is that the formula in this causal structure differs from the usual formula.

In the paper by [Breskin et al. 2018](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5882566/) they consider a DAG similar to the one provided above (except they have an arrow from $A \rightarrow Y$).

They give the following equality (translated to the variable names given here):
$$ E[Y^a] = \sum_l E[Y | A=a,L=l,C=0] \Pr(L=l | A=a)$$
This is distinct from the usual g-computation formula we usually see. See the proof in the paper for the math and ideas that lead to this form. They also demonstrate this with simulations.

A similar proof is given in Example 1 of my paper [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC9156549/). It considers a modification of the DAG shown above, but shares some similarities.

**Update**:

I had some extra time so I am returning to this question to show how the corresponding g-computation algorithm can be implemented. I am going to do this with Python and my package `delicatessen` for fitting the models. The data generating mechanism comes from the Breskin et al. paper referenced above.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from delicatessen import MEstimator
from delicatessen.estimating_equations import ee_regression, ee_glm
from delicatessen.utilities import inverse_logit

# Generating the data
np.random.seed(20231107)
n = 1000000
d = pd.DataFrame()
d['A'] = np.random.binomial(n=1, p=0.5, size=n)
d['U'] = np.random.binomial(n=1, p=0.3, size=n)
d['W'] = np.random.binomial(n=1, p=0.2 + 0.4*d['A'] + 0.3*d['U'], size=n)
d['S'] = np.random.binomial(n=1, p=0.1 + 0.8*d['W'], size=n)
d['Y'] = np.random.binomial(n=1, p=0.3 + 0.5*d['U'] - 0.2*d['A'], size=n)
d['I'] = 1
ds = d.loc[d['S'] == 0].copy()
```

As a comparison, we can use the full data on Y to assess the causal effect

```py
# Truth
X = np.asarray(d[['I', 'A']])
y = np.asarray(d['Y'])

def psi(theta):
    return ee_glm(theta, X=X, y=y, distribution='binomial', link='identity')

estr = MEstimator(psi, init=[0.5, -0.2])
estr.estimate()
```

which gives the estimated causal effect as `-0.20066583`. When ignoring the selection bias, we get an answer of `-0.23594802` and when adjusting for W via a model we get `-0.25898981`. The following code provides an implementation of g-computation for this type of selection bias problem as an estimating equation

```py
# G-computation
d['Y'] = np.where(d['S'] == 0, d['Y'], -9999)
d['AW'] = d['A'] * d['W']
X = np.asarray(d[['I', 'A', 'W', 'AW']])
y = np.asarray(d['Y'])
a = np.asarray(d['A'])
s = np.asarray(d['S'])
da = d.copy()
da['A'] = 1
da['AW'] = d['W']
X1 = np.asarray(da[['I', 'A', 'W', 'AW']])
da['A'] = 0
da['AW'] = 0
X0 = np.asarray(da[['I', 'A', 'W', 'AW']])


def psi(theta):
    # Subsetting parameters out
    rd, r1, r0 = theta[0:3]
    beta = theta[3:]

    # Outcome nuisance model, Pr(Y | A,W,S=0)
    ee_out = ee_regression(beta, X=X, y=y, model='logistic')
    ee_out = ee_out * (1-s)  # subsetting to S=0
    y1hat = inverse_logit(np.dot(X1, beta))  # Predicted Y^{1}
    y0hat = inverse_logit(np.dot(X0, beta))  # Predicted Y^{0}

    # Risk functions
    ee_r1 = a*(y1hat - r1)         # Mean Y^{1} among A=1
    ee_r0 = (1-a)*(y0hat - r0)     # Mean Y^{0} among A=0
    ee_rd = np.ones(y.shape) * (r1 - r0 - rd)  # ACE

    return np.vstack([ee_rd, ee_r1, ee_r0, ee_out])


estr = MEstimator(psi, init=[0., 0.5, 0.5, -0.3, -1., 0.6, 0.3])
estr.estimate()
```

(starting values are mildly informative to speed up the fitting process). Here, the procedure estimates the average causal effect as `-0.19898929` which is close to the truth.

Comment: My intuition was that we should be averaging over Pr[L=l|A=a] and for once it's turned out to be right... I'm reading the cited papers now for the details now. Thanks!